# Why can the arcs in my lighter cross each other?

Tags: electricity

I have a plasma lighter, which is just an arc that is hot enough to burn things. However the specific version of the lighter I have has 2 anodes and 2 cathodes, and the arcs formed by each pair cross each other and make an 'X' shape, like so. https://assets.greenrushdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/redwood_plaz-x-1.jpg

If the electrons were moving along the shortest path available, this would not be possible, since the diagonals are always longer than the edges. So what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

To get breakdown in air for that far, you need a lot of voltage.  Since it's run by a small battery, that must mean that the arcs aren't continuous.

I don't know anything about these lighters, so this is just a guess.  But I presume that these are electronically switched and only one diagonal pair is "firing" at one time.  They appear to be continuous from the ionization glow and persistence of vision.

Comment: This wasn't something I had considered, but it seemed correct so I tried testing it by waving it in the air and seeing if the afterimage was of X's or of slashes. However, in the presence of significant airflow, the arcs stopped being crossed, and instead lined up top to top, bottom to bottom, as I would expect them to have done originally. I am upvoting this response, because it was a good explanation for the phenomenon, but it can't have been correct.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't able to find any specific information on this device.

Comment: Maybe this is a result of the fact that parallel wires carrying current in the same direction attract each other?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm pretty sure that I've discovered the reason for this.

The arcs experience a magnetic force in any configuration except for the one in which they are all mutually perpendicular, and the force that they experience always brings them closer to that configuration.